# javascript regex capturing parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace

I don't really get the concept on [capturing parentheses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses) when dealing with javascript regex. I don't understand why we need parentheses for the following example

```
var x = "{xxx} blah blah blah {yyy} and {111}";
x.replace( /{([^{}]*)}/g , 
          function(match,content) {
               console.log(match,content);
               return "whatever";
});

//it will print
{xxx} xxx
{yyy} yyy
{111} 111
```

so when i drop the parentheses from my pattern `x` the results give a different value

```
x.replace( /{[^{}]*}/g , 
          function(match,content) {
               console.log(match,content);
               return "whatever";
});

//it will print
{xxx} 0
{yyy} 37
{111} 49
```

so the content values now become numeric value which i have no idea why. Can someone explains what's going on behind the scene ?

Comment: the second code will output 0,21,31 which are the index of the matches (not the ones you provided)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), the parameters to the function will be, in order:

- The matched substring.
- Any groups that are defined, if there are any.
- The index in the original string where the match was found.
- The original string.

So in the first example, `content` will be the string which was captured in group 1. But when you remove the group in the second example, `content` is actually the index where the match was found.

Comment: Which is a dumb interface (allowing variadic parameters in the middle), but it is what it is .. and this answers explains the observed behavior.

Comment: function( match, p1, offset, string ) is the correct function for /{([^{}]*)}/g, while function( match, offset, string ) is the correct function for /{[^{}]*}/g. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is useful with replacement of texts.

For example, I have this string "one two three four" that I want to reverse like "four three two one". To achieve that I will use this line of code:

```
var reversed = "one two three four".replace(/(one) (two) (three) (four)/, "$4 $3 $2 $1");
```

Note how $n represents each word in the string.

Another example: I have the same string "one two three four" and I want to print each word twice:

```
var eachWordTwice = "one two three four".replace(/(one) (two) (three) (four)/, "$1 $1 $2 $2 $3 $3 $4 $4");
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers:

> The offset of the matched substring within the total string being
>   examined. (For example, if the total string was "abcd", and the
>   matched substring was "bc", then this argument will be 1.)

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

"Specifying a function as a parameter" section

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis are used to capture/replace only a portion of the match. For instance, when I use it to match phone numbers that may or may not have extensions. This function matches the whole string (if the `if` is correct), so the entire string is replaced, but I am only using a specific types of characters in a specific order, with whitespace or other("() -x") characters allowed in the input.

It will always output a string formatted to (651) 258-9631 x1234 if given 6512589631x1234 or 1 651 258 9631 1234. It also doesn't allow (or in this case format) toll-free numbers as they aren't allowed in my field.

```
function phoneNumber(v) {
// take in a string, return a formatted string (651) 651-6511 x1234
if (v.search(/^[1]{0,1}[-(\s.]{0,1}(?!800|888|877|866|855|900)([2-9][0-9]{2})[-)\s.]{0,2}([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.\s]{0,2}([0-9]{4})[\s]*[x]{0,1}([0-9]{1,5}){1}$/gi) !== -1) {return v.replace(/^[1]{0,1}[-(\s.]{0,1}(?!800|888|877|866|855|900)([2-9][0-9]{2})[-)\s.]{0,2}([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.\s]{0,2}([0-9]{4})[\s]*[x]{0,1}([0-9]{1,5}){1}$/gi,"($1) $2-$3 x$4"); }
if (v.search(/^[1]{0,1}[-(\s.]{0,1}(?!800|888|877|866|855|900)([2-9][0-9]{2})[-)\s.]{0,1}([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.\s]{0,2}([0-9]{4})$/gi) !== -1) { return v.replace(/^[1]{0,1}[-(\s.]{0,1}(?!800|888|877|866|855|900)([2-9][0-9]{2})[-)\s.]{0,1}([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.\s]{0,2}([0-9]{4})$/gi,"($1) $2-$3"); }
return v;
}
```

What this allows me to do is gather the area code, prefix, line number, and an optional extension, and format it the way I need it (for users who can't follow directions, for instance).

So it you input 6516516511x1234 or "(651) 651-6511 x1234", it will match one regex or another in this example.

Now what is happening in your code is as [@amine-hajyoussef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1117720/amine-hajyoussef) said - The index of the start of each match is being returned. Your use of that code would be better serviced by `match` for example one (text returned), or `search` for the index, as in example two. [p.s.w.g's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1715579/p-s-w-g) answer expands.